# Dictionary counter

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, count

Let's say I have a sequence "ADFG"
The script should see if it's in the list (A,T,G,C) and then if it is, get the key from the dictionary and add 1.
So, for the sequence "ADFG", it would add 1 to variable "a" and to variable "g", and add 2 to variable "error".
However, while the script isn't returning an error, the dicio[i]+=1 line isn't adding up anything.... Any ideas?
I know there are simpler ways to do this but I would like to use a dictionary.

```
seq= input ("dna seq:").upper()  
a,t,g,c,error=0,0,0,0,0
dicio= {"A":a,"T":t,"G":g,"C":c}
for i in seq:
    if i in ("A","T","G","C"):
        dicio[i]+=1
        a+=1
    else:
        error+=1

print("A={:.2f} %".format(a/len(seq)*100))
print("T={:.2f} %".format(t/len(seq)*100))
print("G={:.2f} %".format(g/len(seq)*100))
print("C={:.2f} %".format(c/len(seq)*100))
print("Da sequencia,{:.2f} % sao erros".format(error/len(seq)*100))
```

Comment: add a programming language tag

Comment: you cannot use dictionary assignment to change a simple variable such as `a` or `g`. Just use `dicio['A']` and `dicio['G']` below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean that t,g,c are unaffected by the adding in `dicio`

That's normal: dictionary has not taken the references of the variables, but just copied the initial values. You're not updating them when you add 1 to the values of the dictionary.
(`a` is a special case in your code, it gets updated in all cases, but maybe it's a bug, at least not logical compared to the rest of the code).

To do what you want, you need to forget about your `t,g` ... variables and just use `dicio` to display the results:

```
for i in ("A","T","G","C"):
   print("{}={:.2f} %".format(i,dicio[i]/len(seq)*100))
```

(as a bonus you'll save a lot of copy/paste :))

BTW: If you want to initialize the dictionary and keep keys ordered you need `ordereddict`:

```
from Collections import ordereddict

dicio = ordereddict()
for k in ("A","T","G","C"):
   dicio[k] = 0
```

Comment: I've noticed that python prints out a specific order.
like so:
T=20.51 %
C=28.21 %
G=20.51 %
A=30.77 %

How can i define the order? this seems weird since it doens't even follow the order of the dictionary...

Comment: see my edit. dictionaries do not guarantee key sorting. `ordereddict` is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to use dictionaries to store the values instead of having `a,t,g,c` be connected to it and updated at the same time. Here's some code that uses some dictionary features to make it a little more concise:

```
seq= input ("dna seq:").upper()  
a,t,g,c,error=0,0,0,0,0
dicio= {"A":a,"T":t,"G":g,"C":c}
for i in seq:
    if i in dicio.keys():
        dicio[i]+=1
    else:
        error+=1

for key,value in dicio.items():
    print("{}={:.2f} %".format(key,value/len(seq)*100))

print("Da sequencia,{:.2f} % sao erros".format(error/len(seq)*100))
```